# How do I keep the current tab active after a page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently using tabs and want to select the same tab after a user has posted data and the page reloads.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
        $items.mousedown(function() {
            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var index = $items.index($(this));
            $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
        }).eq(0).mousedown();
    });
</script>
```

Tabs:

```
<div id="vtab">
    <ul>
        <li class="user"><a href="#">User</a></li>
        <li class="category"><a href="#">Category</a></li>
    </ul>
<!--user-->        
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
<!--category-->        
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Still nobody can help me with this code? Now I learn and I try to understand how it work because I need this in a project. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to post the data via [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) aka AJAX. That way, your whole page won't redirect. The other solution is to put the active tab in the URL. That has the side benefit of allowing bookmarks to return to the correct tab too. To put the tab in the URL, look at [pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (and consider a polyfill/backwards compatible approach to work with browsers that do not have pushstate).

Comment: I'm not so good in javascript. Can you give me an example following my code? Sorry!